# Comparing 2 string arrays using Linq and Regex for a partial match

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, string-comparison

I have an array of search words and a second array that needs to be searched, returning true or false depending if any of the strings in the 2nd array contain text from the first. I tried using linq but I can't get it to return true if any of the values in the second array contain more than just those search words. I was thinking of using Regex maybe in combination with the linq query but I'm not sure how that would work. Here is what I was tried

```
string[] gsdSearchVerbiage =
  {
    "grade", 
     "transcript",
     "gsd"
  };

  string[] tableColumns = new string []
  {
    "maxsgrades",
     "somethingElse",
   };

bool gsdFound = tableColumns.Any(
   x => gsdSearchVerbiage.Contains(x));
```

This returns false. I understand why it's returning false but I can't figure out how to fix it. If the answer is to use a regular expression I couldn't figure out how to do that over 2 arrays...

Comment: So is the idea that tableColumns is searched for whether it contains any of the words in gsdSearchVerbiage? Should this be case insensitive? At the moment I'm guessing this should return true as 'maxsgrades' contains the word 'grade'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last statement should be

```
bool gsdFound = tableColumns.Any(
    x => gsdSearchVerbiage.Any(y => x.Contains(y)));
```

since you're trying to know if the current item of tableColumns (x) contains any of gsdSearchVerbiage words (y)